# React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency or Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, formik, usecallback

In a `useEffect` , I check if an object exists,

if the object exists I call a `useCallBack` function which will fill in the values of a form via `formik`

Here is the problem :

1- if I do not fill in the formDef in the dependencies of `useCallBack`, I get a message telling me

```
 React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'formDef'.
```

and in this case I cannot build my branch following this error.

2 - if I fill in the `formDef` in the dependencies of `useCallBack`, the function loops infinitely, with the following error message:

```
 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls
 setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array,
`enter code here` or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
```

**useCallBack**:

```
 const InitialiseTypeStorage = useCallback(() => {
   if (type) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(type.type)) {
      formDef.setFieldValue(key, value);
      }
   }
 }, [type]);
```

**useFormik** :

```
 const formDef = useFormik({
   initialValues: formTypedValues,
   validateOnMount: true,
   validationSchema,
   enableReinitialize: true,
   validateOnChange: true,
   onSubmit: (values) => handleMappingType(values),
 });
```

**useEffect** :

```
  useEffect(() => {
   InitialiseTypeStorage();
  }, [InitialiseTypeStorage]);
```

Is there a solution to avoid these two error messages?

Comment: If you are sure of what you are doing  you can add an ignore to the rule

Comment: @phoenixstudio yes in case there are no other solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, simply destructure the formik can get rid of the warning.

```
 const { setFieldValue } = formDef;

 const InitialiseTypeStorage = useCallback(() => {
   if (type) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(type.type)) {
      setFieldValue(key, value);
      }
   }
 }, [type, setFieldValue]);
```